# Register Custom Operator in Tensorflow Lite C API

Tags: android, c, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am running tensorflow lite on Android using the C API. My model requires the operator `RandomStandardNormal` which was recently implemented as a custom op prototype in tensorflow `v2.4.0-rc0` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/11823c6179a5e2ca6ac4f8480aa00c42c772885e)

`TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddCustomOp()` function is listed in [tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_experimental.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0-rc0/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_experimental.h#L65):

```c
TFL_CAPI_EXPORT void TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddCustomOp(
    TfLiteInterpreterOptions* options, const char* name,
    const TfLiteRegistration* registration, int32_t min_version,
    int32_t max_version);
```

Looking at [this example & thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35689#issuecomment-670624092), I am trying to use `TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddCustomOp` like this:

```c
// create model and interpreter options
TfLiteModel *model = TfLiteModelCreateFromFile("path/to/model.tflite");
TfLiteInterpreterOptions* options = TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate();

// register custom ops
TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddCustomOp(options, "RandomStandardNormal", Register_RANDOM_STANDARD_NORMAL(), 1, 1);

// create the interpreter
TfLiteInterpreter* interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options);
TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter);
```

I see that the `Register_RANDOM_STANDARD_NORMAL()` function is defined in the `tflite::ops::custom` C++ namespace in [tensorflow/lite/kernels/custom_ops_register.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0-rc0/tensorflow/lite/kernels/custom_ops_register.h#L30). But, when I try to include this in my C file the compiler complains because `namespace` is an unknown type in C.

How can I register a custom operator using the tensorflow lite C API? Do I need to use a C++ compiler in order to use the C API with this custom operator because it was defined in C++?

NOTE: I include `//tensorflow/lite/kernels:custom_ops` in the bazel BUILD deps when compiling `libtensorflowlite_c.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On tensorflow [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44664), @jdduke suggested a temporary workaround:

- add a `extern "C"` wrapper head to `custom_ops_register.h`

```
extern "C" {
TFL_CAPI_EXPORT TfLiteRegistration* TfLiteRegisterRandomStandardNormal();
}
```

- add a `extern "C"` wrapper implementation to `random_standard_normal.cc`

```
extern "C" {
TFL_CAPI_EXPORT TfLiteRegistration* TfLiteRegisterRandomStandardNormal() {
  return tflite::ops::custom::Register_RANDOM_STANDARD_NORMAL();
}
}
```

- ensure `//tensorflow/lite/kernels:custom_ops` is included as a dependency in `tensorflow/lite/c/BUILD`

```
tflite_cc_shared_object(
    name = "tensorflowlite_c",
    linkopts = select({
        "//tensorflow:ios": [
            "-Wl,-exported_symbols_list,$(location //tensorflow/lite/c:exported_symbols.lds)",
        ],
        "//tensorflow:macos": [
            "-Wl,-exported_symbols_list,$(location //tensorflow/lite/c:exported_symbols.lds)",
        ],
        "//tensorflow:windows": [],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "-z defs",
            "-Wl,--version-script,$(location //tensorflow/lite/c:version_script.lds)",
        ],
    }),
    per_os_targets = True,
    deps = [
        ":c_api",
        ":c_api_experimental",
        ":exported_symbols.lds",
        ":version_script.lds",
        "//tensorflow/lite/kernels:custom_ops", # here
    ],
)
```

- modify my C++ code to call this new wrapper function

```
TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddCustomOp(options, "RandomStandardNormal", TfLiteRegisterRandomStandardNormal(), 1, 1);
```

And it worked! My tensors finally allocated on android :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was answered on Github via this workaround:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44664#issuecomment-723310060